# Простой Junit test для метода в Java

Tags: java, junit

Только начинаю постигать полезности тестирования.
Перечитал много ответов здесь и в гугле в целом, но ответа не нашел.

Имеется метод (кто ради интереса писал игры на JavaRush, тому будет знакомо):

```java
public void move() {

            if (super.x < RoadManager.LEFT_BORDER)
                x = RoadManager.LEFT_BORDER;
            else if (super.x > RoadManager.RIGHT_BORDER - width)
                x = RoadManager.RIGHT_BORDER - width;
```

Как видите, имеется 2 условия. Насколько я понял, под if и else if нужно писать два разных теста. Однако никак не могу понять, как это протестировать с помощью JUnit.

UPD: 
Пробовал сделать это в два действия (для if): 
сперва assertTrue проверил правдивость условия, далее уже assertEquals сравнил ожидаемое значение с актуальным, но это неверно :(

Comment: как правило смысл теста в том, чтобы что-то дать методу и получить ожидаемый результат, а не черный ящик как в приведенном примере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите unit-тесты, то вам нужно проверять не результат логических выражений в условии *внутри функции*, а результат выполнения **самой функции**. Вы, вероятно, неправильно поняли суть юнит-тестов. А она в том, что мы проверяем работу **всей функции**, а не того, что происходит *внутри* неё.

Пример того, что можно сделать вам для проведения теста. Задаем какое-то значение для super.x, задаем RoadManager.LEFT_BORDER и RoadManager.RIGHT_BORDER. Делаем это всё ручками через сеттеры, если они у вас определены, либо другим способом, который может задать значения так, чтобы мы знали их точно(или хотя бы ожидали определенное значение переменной в начале функции. Соответственно, мы можем посчитать, что будет в if'ах и можем предсказать, что должно произойти в результате выполнения функции.
Далее, мы вызываем нашу функцию, затем assertEquals, в котором пишем ожидаемое значение и геттер для переменной x, которая должна меняться в результате выполнения функции. Делается это всё не в том же классе, а в отдельном классе, который обычно помещается в папку 'src'--'test', структура которой далее соответствует папке 'src'--'main'

И ещё, что, по-вашему, должно произойти, если

`super.x >= RoadManager.LEFT_BORDER & super.x <= RoadManager.RIGHT_BORDER`?
 Вы учитываете это при написании теста?

Comment: пока ждал ответа, уже разобрался в сути unit тестов и понял, что очень много методов в моем коде (а вернее не совсем моем) написаны неверно, так как протестировать их просто невозможно, не переписывая их заново. По поводу вашего вопроса: в самой программе такого условия не может случится априори) Спасибо за ответ. И вдогонку, в каких случаях нужно использовать mock-и (подмену)? Можете вкратце, пожалуйста, написать :)

Comment: Про моки и подмену рассказать подробно не смогу, т.к. не использовал их, знаю только отдаленно про mock. Его можно использовать, когда нужна реализация какого-то интерфейса, но используя анонимный класс нам придется переопределять кучу методов интерфейса. "Замокав" данный интерфейс мы сможем просто сказать ему "делай так-то, если тебе приходит такой-то метод", не переопределяя все методы в интерфейсе. Это только один пример использования, который я встречал, так что лучше почитайте где-то ещё. :)

Comment: в любом случае, вы мне ответили на мой вопрос! Спасибо еще раз!